# Loading <iframe> after pressed button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I press button after that appears div in which shows "loading" and loads iframe.
So, showing div I can do via jQuery, but how to load iframe after event?

[**Here is my working code as i want**](http://jsfiddle.net/gVBQE/17/)

Comment: There is something missing in your question, _codes?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `src` attribute of the iframe the moment you want it to start loading (set it to `""` by default):

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
  $('iframe#myIframe').attr('src', url);
});
```

You can also handle events for when the iframe finishes loading:

```
$('iframe#myIframe').load(function() {
  // do stuff...
});
```

Comment: Everything you need is in the post, what else do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

So I understood what I needed:

```
<iframe id="chgMe" src="Source1.htm">Frames are not supported on your browser.</iframe>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('chgMe').src='Source2.htm'">Next</button>
```

Comment: Since he's clearly using jQuery, it's pointless to not-use it's features to get the element and set the src.